# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function \x90\xf9\x8a\x0f\xed*() in \x80\x07 on line 4667

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Has anyone ever seen anything like this?  It happens intermittently on one of my servers running Apache2 with Xcache and PHP 5.3.3.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure, but it appears suspiciously like someone trying to use a buffer overflow to call a specific system function at address 0x0f8af990. See [this link](http://forum.intern0t.net/exploits-vulnerabilities-pocs/4141-php-5-3-5-socket_connect-buffer-overflow-vulnerability.html) for example.

Comment: That link is dead.